# Make wrapped F# SRTP function generic

Tags: generics, logging, f#, inline

I have a generic function using statically resolved type parameters

```
let inline divide a b = a / b
```

with signature `^a -> ^a -> ^a`

I can create a wrapper function

```
let log f = 
    let result = f()
    printfn "Result: %A" result
    result
```

If I then create a function like

```
let loggedDivide a b = log (fun () -> divide a b)
```

its signature is `float -> float -> float` instead of `^a -> ^a -> ^a`, meaning

```
loggedDivide 2.0 5.0
loggedDivide 2 5 //error
```

How can this be done?

Note, something like this misses the point of trying to reuse functions

```
let logValue a = printfn "Result: %A" a
divide 2.0 5.0 |> logValue
divide 2 5 |> logValue
```

And things doesn't remain generic this way

```
let logValueAndReturn a = 
    printfn "Result: %A" a
    a

let divideAndLog a b = divide a b |> logValue
divideAndLog 2.0 5.0
divideAndLog 2 5 //error
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to make your derived function inline as well:

```
let inline loggedDivide a b = log (fun () -> divide a b)
```

That will allow constraints to be propagated:

```
val inline loggedDivide :
  a: ^a -> b: ^b ->  ^c
    when ( ^a or  ^b) : (static member ( / ) :  ^a *  ^b ->  ^c)
```

The reason for this is that SRTP's is an F# compiler feature, which is resolved at compile-time, so functions get specialized by inlining at the call site.

If you want your function to remaing generic, it has to be inline.

Note that the reason you get your function inferred as operating with `int` is because that's the default for `\` and other math operators. Otherwise you would get an error indicating ambiguity.

Comment: That's really obvious now that you say it. Thanks! It's turtles all the way down.